# EXCEL VBA - Creating a dynamic dropdown based on a cell range and a string

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, drop-down-menu, filter

Ok, so I currently have a dropdown that is populated from a range on a separate sheet.

I want to be able to decrease the values in the dropdown by only adding values that have a text value from another cell within each values text.

for example:
Cell A1 says 'table'
Cell A2 is the dropdown that pulls in the values from the range
The range has 'table','large table','stool'

Currently the dropdown would bring in all of the values. In this instance I would want it to bring just 'table' and 'large table' as they both have 'table' in them.

an example of my file can be found here
http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

Please help.. I'm tearing my hair out!

Thanks
Mike

Comment: where is your code? what do you have so far?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: @K_B I think that is a little unfair as I have looked for other questions on this and all of them that seem relevant are not quite what I am looking for. I cant see any option to upload a file on here so I wrote out an example in my question. If you can tell me how I would upload an excel spreadsheet on here then I can do that for you.

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/29/excel-data-validationcreate-dynamic-dependent-lists-vba/) would get you started ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it without VBA:

(all instructions to be done on the sheet with the items list unless otherwise stated):
[image]

1. Search for the text provided. In C2, enter `=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH('Choose Items'!$A$2,A2)))` and copy down
2. Count hits in D2: `=IF(C2,1,0)`, in D3: `=IF(C3,D2+1,D2)` - copy down
3. Create dynamic list: in F2:F9, place the numbers 1-8. In G2, use this formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,MATCH(F2,$D$2:$D$9,0)),IF(F2=1,"No match",""))` and copy down.
4. Create a dynamic named range - in the Name Manager (*Formulas*->*Name Manager*), insert a new name *ItemsDynamic* and provide `=OFFSET(Items!$G$2:$G$9,0,0,MAX(Items!$D$2:$D$9,1),1)` as the formula.
5. Use the new *ItemsDynamic* as the source of your dropdown in the field validation

Done! Check [this file](https://mega.co.nz/#!rcZhwJZL!NrHtPXCwqtdu6CSjQJS3qmPMQrFiHgAtVymLA1cQArU) for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a more simplified answer.

First group the items in the sheet 'Items' in a helper column, say Column 'C' using the formula (for C2) and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT($A2,LEN($A2)-FIND(" ",$A2)),$A2)
```

Now in the sheet 'Choose Items', for cell B2, use the following as the validation list's source -

```
=OFFSET(Items!$A$1,MATCH('Choose Items'!$A2,Items!$C$2:$C$10,0),,COUNTIF(Items!$C$2:$C$10,'Choose Items'!$A2),)
```

You can fill down to extend the validation to other rows of Column 'B'

In case your data in the sheet 'Items' needs to be extended to rows beyond 10, appropriately change the offset function's scope of the match and the countif functions to encompass the entire data (after having the grouping in column 'C' as discussed earlier).

Make sure the list in sheet 'Items' is sorted on the helper column (Ascending or Descending), which is column 'C' in this case.